# Questions on perfect squares and perfect cubes

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Which of the following are true?

1:for every positive integer **m**, there is a positive integer **n** such that **m+n+1** is a perfect square.

2:for every positive integer **m**, there is a positive integer **n** such that **mn+1** is a perfect cube

3:for every positive integer **m**, there is a positive integer **n** such that **m+n+1** is a perfect cube

4:for every positive integer **m**, there is a positive integer **n** such that **mn+1** is a perfect square

Answer (score 2):

I'll do the first one, which should help on (3)...

Given some **m** $\geq 1$ 
Consider $(m + 1)^2 = m^2 + 2m + 1$ 
The left hand side $(n + m + 1)$ will equal a perfect square (namely, $m^2 + 2m + 1$) if we let $n = m^2 + m > 0$

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody but the problem was that the book gave the answer that only statement 1 and 2 are true but i was getting all of them true. i am new to such forums and shall be thankful to know how to put up questions better.

Comment: @Harsh: That's fine! Notice that I explicitly stated that our value of n was positive. When you try a similar approach to (3), can you come to such a conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

Second is easy too. Let's assume that $mn+1$ is a perfect cube and recall that $(a + 1)^3 = a^3 + 3a^2 + 3a+ 1$. If both of them are equal we get $(mn + 1) = a^3 + 3a^2 + 3a+ 1$ which is the same as $mn = a(a^2 + 3a + 3)$. This means that for every *m* if you take $n = m^2 + 3m + 3$ then $mn+1$ will be a perfect cube.

Comment: $n = m^2 + 3m + 3$ you mean of course.

Comment: @ypercube: Thanks, fixed.

Comment: And this answer will help on (4)... which should read "square" at the end??